$M^3$ admits $Sol$ geometry if and only if $\pi_1M$ is virtually solvable but not virtually nilpotent?
Let $M$ be a closed, orientable, irreducible 3-manifold and having an infinite fundamental group. Is it true that $M$ admits $Sol$ geometry if and only if $\pi_1M$ is virtually solvable but not virtually nilpotent?
Also, is there a reference for this question?

You don't need to assume infinite, since finite implies virtually nilpotent.

What you ask for is true and a reference can be extracted from pp. 19-20 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0202.
